# Entity Framework Adding all child entitys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table called quote, who has many services, each service has many staff attached.

```
quote:
    public int Id {get; set;}
    pbulic ICollection<Services> services {get;set}

Services:
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int QuoteId {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("QutoeId")]
    public Quote quote {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Staff> Staff {get;set;}

Staff:
    public Int Id {get;set;}
    public ServiceId {get;set;
    [ForeignKey("StaffId")]
    public Service service {get;set;}
    public string StaffName {get;set;}
```

This isnt my real database so ignore any typos. (or incorrect coding etiquette.

The problem I have. Is I want to save the tables to the database.
I have a Quote object, with many services with many staff.

Do I have to itterate through them all to add them manually to the database.

I simply tried:

```
dbContext.Quote.Add(quote);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

however this only saved the Quote table to the database and not the children tables. 
Do I have to do something silly like:

```
 foreach (var staff in Quote.Services.Staff)
 {
     dbContext.Staff.Add(staff)
 }
 foreach (var service in Quote.Services)
 {   
     dbContext.Services.Add(services)
 }
```

Comment: can you please take a few minutes and format your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to simply add child tables to both, dbcontext as well as its parent. 
You can try this as mentioned below:

```
dbContext.Quote.Add(quote);
foreach (var service in Quote.Services)
{   
    quote.services .Add(service);
    dbContext.Services.Add(service);
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Similarly add staff object to its parent service object and dbcontext as well

Comment: Thanks. I have done it this way. I was just making sure there was no way to do it cascading automatically.

Comment: Usually the EF iterates also the collections and adds the new objects (object not attached to context). I.E. you need to read related objects (i.e. Services) from database or the EF will add the same service 2 times (well is not your case because all the ids are autogenerated but if the ids are string it happen). Anyway, your code is not the right code (missing different virtual keyword) and I also suggest to use fluent interface to configure at least relationships. In this case you can avoid to insert QuoteId and ServiceId in classes.